# How to Place a vertical line between each image?

Tags: html, css

I would like to place a vertical line between each image, I have tried several things but without success.

Here is an idea of the final result. There is a vertical gray line between the two images. 
How to create the vertical line?

[image]

```css
.background-contact{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  position: absolute;

}

.logo5{
  padding-top: -70px;
  padding-left: 38px;
}

.title-contact-1{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-contact-1{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 22%;
  left: -12%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.logo6{
  padding-top: 35px;
  left: -80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-contact">
  <img class="logo5" src="https://i.ibb.co/0YyTszS/title-icon1.png" >
  <span class="title-contact-1">Telephone</span>
  <span class="text-contact-1">Just For VIP Member</span>
  <img class="logo6" src="https://i.ibb.co/026Fs1B/title-icon2.png" >
  <span class="title-contact-1">E-mail Us</span>
  <span class="text-contact-1">admin@superbtc.biz</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding 2 divs, with `float: left;` on the first and `float: right;` on the second, both set to `width: 50%;`. Then you can address spacing and padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do the pixel perfect but something like this:

```css
.background-contact{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;

}

.background-contact__block {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.background-contact__block + .background-contact__block {
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.title-contact-1{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-contact-1{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}

.logo{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.background-contact__name {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-contact">
  <div class="background-contact__block">
    <div class="background-contact__name">
      <img class="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/0YyTszS/title-icon1.png" >
      <span class="title-contact-1">Telephone</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-contact-1">Just For VIP Member</span>
  </div>
  <div class="background-contact__block">
    <div class="background-contact__name">
      <img class="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/026Fs1B/title-icon2.png" >
      <span class="title-contact-1">E-mail Us</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-contact-1">admin@superbtc.biz</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you a lot Dmitrii !!! I was stuck since 2 days !! Thank you it's ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

to create a border you can use

```
border: (width) (style) (color);
```

This will make a border all around the element, to select one side you can use

```
border-left:
border-right:
border-top:
border-bottom:
```

But here your css is very strange, I recommend you to use the less as possible absolute positioning.

Here a better way do write that :

```css
.contact-item {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-item img,
.contact-item h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.border-left {
  border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-contact">
  <div class="contact-item">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0YyTszS/title-icon1.png">
    <h1>Telephone</h1>
    <p>text<p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="contact-item border-left">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/026Fs1B/title-icon2.png">
    <h1>Email Us</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can also use :

```
element::last-child {
    border-left: .. .. ..;
}
```