# How to create a horizontal line to be in between image and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal line inserted between the image and text using html and css.

The image is on the very left side of the screen, and the text is on the very right side of the screen. Then the horizontal line inserted "IN THE MIDDDLE" and "VERTICALLY ALIGN CENTER"

I am now facing a very strange problem.
1. If i increase the width of hr over than 80% the text next to it will be break to new line

2. If I scale down the screen the text next to it will also break into a new line, how can I make it responsive without breaking into a new line.

I am very new to html and css please kinldy suggest, I have tried reading and finding solution in the forum it seems very difficult to understand and difficult to be applied

I am very new to html and css please kinldy suggest, I have tried reading and finding solution in the forum it seems very difficult to understand and difficult to be applied

```
hr{
display: inline-block;
margin:auto;
width:80%;
}

img {
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

<img src ="example" alt="Product Image"><p>Healthy Cake</p><hr><p style="padding: 10px; background-color: green;">Promotional Price</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Place a vertical line between each image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961781/how-to-place-a-vertical-line-between-each-image)

Answer (score 1):

`hr` should be used to divide elements **vertically** not horizontally but you can manage this using flexbox on a wrapper

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center ;
}

hr {
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" alt="">
  <hr>
  <p>Product Description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will follow your suggestion. I think I need to study more of flex things.

Comment: when i really put all the code into the website it has some strange behavior, please kindly suggest. 

below is the website
https://reedthai.com/พวงหรีด-test/

below is the link explain the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MmOZsRa3icQfhC5ugRDaUKZ-nbBKMZi/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it may be solve your problem,

Add `margin-top: 25px;` to your `<hr>` style and add `margin-top: 0px;` to your `<h2>` style

I have tried the above mentioned styles and i got like the below screenshot.

[image: i have tried this]